# How to tune cassandra for large baremetal server deployment

Tags: cassandra

I have cassandra deployed on large baremetal servers. 56 core and 756 gb ram 20 TB SSD.( I know its an antipattern but I have no choice to create vm or anything).  Its a 10 node cluster. What settings are important for such deployments.

I have read and write heavy workload. Running into long compaction time leading to read and write timeouts.

I don't see cpu,memory,disk,network being a bottleneck

Comment: it's a very broad topic, you need at least specify what version of Cassandra you're using, current configurations, what exact problems you see in the logs, data model, etc. Companies are usually using external consultants if there is no internal knowledge

Answer (score 0):

So I have a saying with dense node architectures: "Big servers equal big problems."

I can think of a few things off the top of my head which *might* help.

In the `cassandra.yaml`, check these two settings:

```
concurrent_compactors: 2
compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 16
```

Specifically, `concurrent_compactors` is one of those that can be set proportional to the number of CPU cores.  I wouldn't go too high, but maybe test it by increasing by a factor of 2, and see if you notice anything.  Also, with your resources, you should be able to set `compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec` at least to 256.  The good news about this one, is that you can set it with `nodetool` ephemerally, just to try it out.

Make sure that the disk-specific settings are optimized for SSDs:

```
disk_optimization_strategy: ssd
trickle_fsync: true
```

And make sure that the servers are set to use the G1GC collector, and you could probably afford to have a large heap of 32GB or so.

Also, take a read through [Amy Tobey's Cassandra 2.1 Tuning Guide](https://tobert.github.io/pages/als-cassandra-21-tuning-guide.html).  She has lots of good info in there that still applies to Cassandra 3.

TBH though, Alex is right.  **The biggest wins are going to be in adjusting your table definitions.**  Cassandra's performance has more to do with data model definition.  If that's not correct, there's very little that any server-side "tuning" can help with.